# Cells do not get updated automatically

Tags: excel

I have a pretty big excel file that I am currently in progress of updating certain areas. I have about 170 similar worksheets that have the same issue as they are almost identical.

The problem I have run into is that some parts of it does not get updated.

| D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =H1-F1 *<- DOES NOT GET UPDATED* |  | =MIN(D3:D999) |  | =MAX(D3:D999) |
| *CELL USED FOR OTHER FORMULAS* |  |  |  |  |
| *CELL USED FOR OTHER FORMULAS* |  |  |  |  |
| *EMPTY CELL* |  |  |  |  |
| 13:29:17 |  |  |  |  |
| *EMPTY CELL* |  |  |  |  |
| 13:30:40 |  |  |  |  |

For example I have =MIN(D3:D999) in CELL(F1) and =MAX(D3:D999) in CELL(H1) which get min and max of D column that contains times (some are empty some are not). This gets calculated automatically and has no issues.

The other cell, which I have =H1-F1 in CELL(D1) does not get updated automatically, or in real time to be more precise.

Only when I update another cell does D1 get updated.

Options -> Formulas -> Workbook calculation -> Set to automatic.

It feels that anything before does not get updated (column A does not get updated if I change column B) but cannot confirm this theory.

I would have no problem with all this if it was "lagging" behind by 1 cell update, but there are more complex formulas that need 2 or 3 updates (even 2 or 3 times pressing f9) which is not a viable option.

The more complex formulas (that require pressing f9 2 or 3 times) get #VALUE error on 1st or 2nd update, and then fixes itself on the next "calculation".

I have even made a new excel file and copied everything to make sure, which has done nothing.

I hope I have explained the problem clearly, and if there is anything that needs expanding or clarifying, please mention and I will do so accordingly.

Comment: Never heard of that. Sure it's not just being slow? Do you have any code in the file?

Comment: It is not slow, I've waited multiple minutes and nothing gets changed until I either press F9 or do anything with another cell. The original file has code included but have since moved everything to another excel file without any VBA and nothing has changed. The workbook did not depend on the VBA code, as it was a simple macro so I can jump to different pages depending on the name.